# How can I achieve the following start activity intent mode

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a broadcast receiver launching a transparent activity while my application is either not launched at all or is in the background. This transparent activity behaves like a pop-up-box that appears on top of the android OS (thus transparent).

If my application is not launched at the moment (exists neither in foreground nor background), when the broadcast receiver triggers the start intent action everything behaves as it should and my transparent activity appears on top of the android OS.

I have another scenario where my application is paused - is in the background. From this state, if my broadcast receiver is triggering the action to start the transparent activity it does so in a way that it moves my last activity on the screen and my 'transparent activity' on top of it thus not being transparent anymore, I can see through it the contents of the activity behind it (from my application). This behavior is not desired and I wan't to change it in a way that when the pop up activity is started, the activity that was before be invisible. How can I do this, how can I hide all other activities from my app in the stack and have only the last one visible  !?

This is how I send the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PopTestActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PopTestActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```